# Appending a stylesheet to the head of an html document using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I'm attempting to add jQuery to an html document before downloading it. I need to append the following to the head of the document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

I have attempted to use the following to do this, but all I end up with is an empty pair of  tags in the document:

```
var head = content.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var jqstyle = document.createElement("link");
    jqstyle.rel = "stylesheet";
    jqstyle.type = "text/css";
    jqstyle.href = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
head.appendChild(jqstyle);
```

Could anybody tell me what I need to do differently?

Thank You

Comment: May I ask why on earth you're making this so complicated?

Comment: `link` elements don't have any content, so of course they are empty. Or do you mean that not even the attributes show up?

Comment: What is `content` in the first line of code above? Without that, it should work just fine.

Comment: @ Jonast92 
1) Lack of experience of web programming generally.
2) The rigid constraints of the project I am trying to create.

I would be more than happy to consider other ways of accomplishing the same goal if you can suggest any.

Comment: Can you explain this part more clearly: "I'm attempting to add jQuery to an html document before downloading it". That sounds odd.

Comment: @user2683117: What you have isn't complicated. It's not using jQuery, but it's not complicated. You can accomplish the same thing with jQuery like this: `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>');` But that will just do what you've already done via the DOM (again: without `content`; I notice you haven't answered my question), so if that's not working, the jQuery version won't work either.

Comment: Check out OPs previous questions, it seems that he's trying to make a Firefox extension inject jQuery into the page the user is viewing.

Comment: If you look closely, the URL you're setting is 404'ing. You forgot the `ui` (`/jqueryui/`) in the URL. `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: I'm trying to build a firefox extension which will allow users to annotate a web page using JQuery sticky notes similar to http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example/ - I decided the way I would go about it would be to append the 2 scripts and stylesheet along with a jQuery function to the head of the html document and then use Save Page As to bring it down. I have been able to add the scripts to the head with no issue using the code shown above however I cannot devise a way of getting the css file linked in the header.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your suggestion, I'm not entirely sure what content is referencing here but it seems necessary to use it within the .js files of my extension as simply using .document has no effect. Sorry if this seems idiotic but I'm litterally doing this by trial and error so don't understand a lot of the inner workings. I had issues adding jQuery to my extension hence putting it directly into a saved html doc, so I will have to find a way to add the css file using JavaScript. The above will produce an opening and closing link tag but with no attributes set.

Answer (score 2):

As Fabricio pointed out, you've missed two letters (u and i) from the url of the css file.

This works fine here (note the difference between the url in the comment and the one actually used):

```
// want to create this and add to the doc head
// <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/css";
link.href = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work.

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>');
```